# Converting an array of arrays into an object with key and value with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

method input: (['name', 'marcus'], ['address', 'New York']

method output: {name: marcus, address: New York}

How do i do it?

```
cont array = [['c','2'],['d','4']];

function objectify()
{
    array.forEach(arrayElement => { for(let i = 0; i<2; i++){
            const obj = Object.assign({array[i][i]}, array[i++])
    }
    return obj;
})

}

console.log(objectify);
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you. [see why you shouldn't post image as a code or an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Comment: i've tried using foreach, but failed

Comment: @MarcusRibas If it failed, not a problem, just shared what you have tried till now. Even though the code is not working

Comment: `data.forEach(d => obj[d[0]] = d[1])`

Comment: i've eddited the post so u can see what i've tried

Comment: @MarcusRibas did you try using `fromEntries()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const data = [['name', 'marcus'], ['address', 'New York']];
const result = Object.fromEntries(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If you are using `forEach` then you don't have to use `for` loop inside it

```
array.forEach(arrayElement => { for(let i = 0; i<2; i++){
            const obj = Object.assign({array[i][i]}, array[i++])
    }
```

**2)** You shouldn't hardcode the length upto which `i` will run, because it can be of any length.

```
for(let i = 0; i<2; i++)
```

If you are using `forEach` then you should loop over the array and get the `key` and `value` and set it into the resultant object.

```js
function objectify(array) {
  const result = {};
  
  array.forEach((o) => {
    const [key, value] = o;
    result[key] = value;
  });

  return result;
}

const array = [
  ["c", "2"],
  ["d", "4"],
];
console.log(objectify(array));
```

Comment: @MarcusRibas Not a problem, Glas I could help